# UserControl, o que é? Quando utilizar?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Estou estudando a melhor forma de fazer um controle de usuários em uma aplicação WPF, mas estou com algumas duvidas referente ao `UserControl` disponível no VS 2015.

Já tenho programado um controle de acesso, ou seja, usuário e *login*, cadastro de usuário e etc., mas agora preciso definir oque cada usuário pode editar, ou apenas visualizar, ou nem se quer visualizar.

O tal do `UserControl` é para esta finalidade? Se sim, como utilizar? Se não, qual alternativa para a minha solução?

Comment: Se der eu respondo depois, mas não tem nada a ver com permissões, controle de acesso, nada disso. É um objeto de interface com usuário (botão, caixa de texto, etc.) personalizado pelo usuário (no caso o programador)

Comment: Bigown boa tarde. Blz, Se conseguir, não deixe de responder suas respostas são ótimas e vem me ajudando muito.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O [`UserControl`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) é um controle do WPF usado como base para o programador criar seus próprios controles (elementos de GUI) compondo outros controles já existentes como se fossem um só. Ele possui vantagens e desvantagens. Ele é diferente do `CustomControl` que é usado para estender um controle específico.

Pode ser usado para criar um controle que seja uma combinação de uma caixa de texto com um botão, por exemplo. Ou pode criar um conjunto de `checkbox` que pode habilitar ou desabilitar alguns de seus membros de acordo com o estado de um deles. Enfim, dá para ser criativo.

Ele tem a ver com objeto de interface com o usuário de uma forma geral. Não tem a ver com permissões e controle de acesso. Ele não deve ser lido como "controle de usuários", e sim um "controle criado pelo usuário (programador)".

É claro que pode-se criar um controle que seja a entrada de dados de um *login*. Mas não isso só será útil se tiver um *design* muito bem planejado, se trabalha em equipe, se for reutilizado várias vezes. É uma programação avançada e não recomendo até ter um domínio muito grande programação em geral e do WPF (que não é fácil fazer direito).

Ele é um meio termo entre um controle básico e um formulário.

Ele não é nem de perto o que está pretendendo fazer com o controle de acesso à usuários, isso é algo mais complexo que não tem nada pronto no .NET menos ainda no WPF que só trata de telas, e pelo que entendi deseja uma funcionalidade que depende de um modelo onde a tela será apenas um elemento final.

Se tiver dúvidas específicas sobre o outro assunto pode fazer em várias perguntas. Me detive ao principal que foi perguntado, dentro deste contexto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado.